# I want to use commands and args section in deployment.yaml file instead of Entrypoint in dockerfile

Tags: kubernetes, dockerfile

I want to replace entrypoint in dockerfile by using commands and args in deployment.yaml "

```
ENTRYPOINT source /vault/secrets/keystoreinfo && exec java -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev /.urandum -jar /app.jar
```

The problem is how to use source command alongwith java command.

deployment.yaml

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-deployment
  labels:
    app: xyz
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: xyz
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: xyz
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: somename
        image: image
        command: ["java"]
        args: ["-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev /.urandum" , "-jar", "/app.jar"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

Comment: What's the issue with the current deployment?

Comment: I am not sure how to set "source /vault/secrets/keystoreinfo" in command and args section. This has to be the first command in order to set the keystore path

Comment: My first inclination would be to read the `/vault/secrets/...` file in an entrypoint wrapper script, not to write it out as a command (either in the Dockerfile or in the Kubernetes deployment).  Make sure to use the standard `.` command to read a file in the current shell context, not the non-standard `source`.  Why do you want to move this bit of complexity out of the Dockerfile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using a shell as an entrypoint for that, e.g.:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-deployment
  labels:
    app: xyz
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: xyz
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: xyz
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: somename
        image: image
        command: ["sh"]
        args: ["-c" , "source /vault/secrets/keystoreinfo && exec java -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev /.urandum -jar /app.jar"]
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```